# How to fix copy of struct to array of structs segfault

Tags: c, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault

I have the following two structs:

```
typedef struct {
    char* key;
    char* value;
} kvpair;

typedef struct {
    kvpair ** array;
    size_t length;
} kvarray;
```

And I want to copy new key and value pairs to the kvarray.  I use realloc to allocate memory for each new item to be added to the kvpair array but struggling to work out how to copy the key and value.

If I do it like this:

```
  kvs->array resized using realloc

    // *** get segfault here!!! how to fix ***
    kvs->array[kvs->length]->key = key;
  kvs->array[kvs->length]->value = value;
```

But if I allocate memory separately for a kvpair* and do this way:

```
kvpair* kvp = malloc(sizeof(kvpair));
// copy key and value

// This below then works
kvs->array[kvs->length] = kvp;
// but there is a memory leak - or seems to be double allocation of memory for same thing
```

How to do this correctly?

The code is below (see // *** get segfault here!!! how to fix *** comment)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct {
    char* key;
    char* value;
} kvpair;

typedef struct {
    kvpair ** array;
    size_t length;
} kvarray;

kvarray * readKVs(const char** array, size_t length);
void freeKVs(kvarray * pairs);

int main() {
    const char* things[] = { "wood=brown\n", "brick=red\n", 
        "grass=green", "hedge=green", "leaf=green" };
    const size_t sz = sizeof(things) / sizeof(things[0]);

    kvarray* kvs = readKVs(things, sz);
    freeKVs(kvs);
}

kvarray * readKVs(const char** array, size_t length) {

    kvarray* kvs = NULL;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        const char* line = array[i];

        if (kvs == NULL) {
            kvs = malloc(sizeof(kvarray));
            kvs->length = 0;
            kvs->array = NULL;
        }

        char * found = strchr(line, '=');
        if (found == NULL) {
            // skip to next line
            continue;
        }

        size_t len = strlen(line);
        size_t pos = found - array[i];

        char* value = NULL;
        if (len > (pos + 1)) {
            // non-blank value
            // length of value is len - pos
            value = malloc(len - (pos + 1));
            strncpy(value, &line[pos + 1], (len - (pos + 1)) - 1);
            // null terminate string
            value[len - (pos + 1) - 1] = '\0';
            printf("value:'%s'\n", value);
        }

        char* key = malloc(found - line + 1);  // +1 for null terminator
        strncpy(key, line, pos);
        // remember strncpy bug!
        key[found - line] = '\0';  // ensure null termination. 
        printf("key:'%s', length=%lu\n", key, strlen(key));

        /*
        // if I allocate an individual pair, then I am duplicating memory so should have to do this below
        kvpair* kvp = malloc(sizeof(kvpair));
        //kvpair kvp = {NULL, NULL};
        printf("about to assign kvs->key = key\n");
        kvp->key = key;
        printf("about to assign kvs->value = value\n");
        kvp->value = value;
        */

        kvs->array = realloc(kvs->array, (kvs->length + 1) * sizeof(kvpair*));

        // I want to be able to do this 2 lines below - but crashes
        // *** get segfault here!!! how to fix ***
        kvs->array[kvs->length]->key = key;
        kvs->array[kvs->length]->value = value;

        kvs->length++;
        printf("kvs->length now=%lu\n", kvs->length);
    }
    return kvs;
}

void freeKVs(kvarray * pairs) {
    if (pairs == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < pairs->length; ++i) {
        free(pairs->array[i]->key);
        free(pairs->array[i]->value);
        free(pairs->array[i]);
    }
    free(pairs);
}
```

Comment: OT: when calling any of the heap allocation functions 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) when calling `realloc`, always assign the returned value to a `void *temp` variable, then check (!=NULL) that temp variable and if nOT NULL then assign to the target variable.  Otherwise, when `realloc` fails, the pointer to the original allocated memory will be overlayed with NULL, resulting in an unrecoverable memory leak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
kvs->array = realloc(kvs->array, (kvs->length + 1) * sizeof(kvpair*));
```

the contents of the new memory allocated will be *indeterminate*, it's not initialized. That means the next line

```
kvs->array[kvs->length]->key = key;
```

you will dereference an invalid pointer `kvs->array[kvs->length]`. That of course will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The solution is of course to make `kvs->array[kvs->length]` point somewhere valid, for example by doing

```
kvs->array[kvs->length] = malloc(sizeof(kvpair));
```

Comment: And then in freeKVs I need to add free(kvs->array); ?

Comment: @AngusComber Every `malloc` (or `realloc`) call needs to be matched by one `free` call.

Comment: More precisely, each `malloc()` or `calloc()` needs to be matched by a `free()`.  One time a `realloc()` needs to be matched by a `free()` is when the 'old space' pointer is NULL; then it behaves like `malloc()`. You should also discount calls to `realloc()` where the new size is zero and the returned pointer is NULL because it frees the memory. (In other words, `realloc()` calls don't always need their own `free()` calls because they change an allocation made by `malloc()` or `calloc()`. There are a few other twists to saga (`aligned_alloc()`, for example). But the general idea is correct.)